# JSONException: Value uid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, jsonexception

I am parsing this

```
{
  "error": false,
  "uid": "1",
  "user": {
    "name": "admin",
    "mail": "ardypranataturnip@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

when I run my code, I've got the error

> JSONException: Value uid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

How do I solve this error ?

```
private void requestLogin() {
    mApiService.loginRequest(etName.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString())
            .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonRESULTS = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                            if (jsonRESULTS.getString("error").equals("false")) {
                                //jika login berhasil maka name yang ada di response api akan di parsing ke aktivity selanjutnya
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "LOGIN BERHASIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                String name = jsonRESULTS.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("result_name", name);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                String error_message = jsonRESULTS.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("debug", "onFailure: ERROR > " + t.toString());
                    loading.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: you cannot convert object User to String, that is why you getting an exception

Comment: Your question has no `uid` key being parsed

Comment: jsonRESULTS.getString("error").equals("false")) . Is this correct??

Comment: I tried to parse the response that you have, used org.json.jar and didn't get any exception: public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject obj;
    String name = "";
    String test = "{ \"error\": false, \"uid\": \"1\",\"user\": {     \"name\": \"admin\",           \"mail\": \"ardypranataturnip@gmail.com\"         }       }";
    try {
      obj = new JSONObject(test);
      name = obj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
      System.out.println(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

Comment: now i got ths error > JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: yes, its work before, but when i try to login again, it doesn't work @RishavChudal

Comment: I was talking to remove the inverted comma from the false.